# Cocos2d - TMX Collision checking during a CCMoveTo action invoked on an instance of CCSprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

The application responds to touches with the following method - invoking movePlayer:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[self.player stopAllActions];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];
CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, self.player.position);
self.distanceToMovePlayer = sqrtf((diff.x*diff.x)+(diff.y*diff.y));
self.playerDestination = touchLocation;
[self movePlayer];
}
```

movePlayer is defined here.  It runs the CCAction that moves the sprite to the touch.

```
- (void)movePlayer{
CCAction *movePlayer = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:self.distanceToMovePlayer/100 position:self.playerDestination];
self.playerMovement = movePlayer;
[self.player runAction:self.playerMovement];
```

}

I have an invisible TMX Layer called meta on the TMXTileMap that indicates a wall or boundary with the following method that runs every frame:

```
- (void)checkCollisions:(CGPoint)position{
CGPoint tileCoordinate = [self tileCoordForPosition:position];
int tileGID = [self.meta tileGIDAt:tileCoordinate];
if(tileGID == 49){
    NSDictionary *properties = [self.meta properties];
    if(properties){
        NSString *collision = properties[@"Collidable"];
        if(collision && [collision isEqualToString:@"True"]){
            [self.player stopAction:self.playerMovement];
        }
    }
```

Whenever the sprite touches a boundary, the action stops and the sprite is simply stuck there because the action is immediately stopping whenever it starts as the sprite is still in the boundary. 
I have tried setting the collision method to return a boolean which is then tested in the CCMoveTo. Is there a way to call a selector each iteration of a CCAction? Something like CCCallBlockN that runs each frame of the action.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i would probably schedule a selector for a CCAction duration, for a per-frame call back. Assuming you also run some kind of animation on the player sprite, and new in cocos2d 2.0+, you could use a CCAnimation, whereby you could register for a notification to be served with some user-data for each frame.

from the CCAnimation.h file :

```
/**  A CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification notification will be broadcasted 
 *   when the frame is displayed with this dictionary as UserInfo. If UserInfo is nil, 
 *   then no notification will be broadcasted. */

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSDictionary *userInfo;
```

ob cit. Not tried, ymmv

Comment: I don't understand.  How will this aid in programming an effective collision detection method?